# Filter Swift Array and Give Indices (Not Values)

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming

I need to filter an array by some condition on its elements, but I need to obtain the *indices* of the elements that passed the test, **not** the elements themselves.

For example: given an array of `Bool`, I want to transform that into an array of `Int` that contains only the indices of the elements of the orginal array that are `true`.

I ***could*** do this:

```
// INPUT array:
let flags = [true, false, true, false]

// OUTPUT array:
var trueIndices = [Int]()

for (index, value) in flags.enumerated() where value == true {
    trueIndices.append(index)
}
```

...but it isn't "swifty" **at all**.

Is there a more elegant way? Something akin to `filter()`, but that returns the indices instead of the elements.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. The **"swiftiness"** in all your answers is TOO DAMN HIGH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly `filter` the indices

```
let flags = [true, false, true, false]    
let trueIndices = flags.indices.filter{ flags[$0] }
```

and

```
let falseIndices = flags.indices.filter{ !flags[$0] }
```

Comment: Oh, it makes sense now. You are filtering the array (?) of all indices with a closure that captures the outer `flags` array, and tests its contents at the current index (`$0`).

Comment: This is "swiftier"

Comment: It's a long way to "think in portals"!

Comment: Of course one could define a `func indices(where isIncluded: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Index]` extension method for collections ...

Comment: Just a reminder: this only works well when subscripting is possible, and possible in `O(1)`. Won't work for sequences

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how much **"swiftier"** it is, but you can also use a consecutive `filter` and `map` operation or just a single `flatMap` instead. For sure, you can declare the array immutable and you don't have to write any explicit loops, both of which are usually considered a more functional approach than your current one.

```
let trueIndices = flags.enumerated().filter{$0.element}.map{$0.offset}
print(trueIndices)
```

Output:

> [0,2]

Using a single `flatMap`:

```
let trueIndices = flags.enumerated().flatMap { (offset, flag) in flag ? offset : nil }
```

Comment: Of course! `enumerated()` gives an array of tuples, I can filter/map _that_. Guess I’ve been coding for too many hours now...

Comment: The flatMap version does not compile in Xcode 9. My suggestion: `flags.enumerated().flatMap { (offset, flag) in flag ? offset : nil }`

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the tip, I've only tested in Xcode 8, but updated my answer, since your solution is more clear anyways

Comment: You probably meant *"declare the array **im**mutable"*

Comment: Yeah, I was editing my wording and forgot to change mutable to immutable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. It's generalizable to sequences, or even collections whose subscripting isn't O(1).

```
let indicesOfTrue = Array(flags.enumerated().lazy.filter{ $0.element }.map{ $0.offset })
```